# Alternative to NSTimer in Background Mode

Tags: ios, nstimer, cllocationmanager, uibackgroundtask

I am creating an app that needs to send the user's location to the server every 15 minutes regardless of whether it is in the Foreground or in the Background. I have been able to do this using an NSTimer that runs for 15 minutes and sends the location. However, for several hours it seems to fail. I have read somewhere at StackOverFlow that NSTimer is not allowed by iOS 7 to run in the background. Is there any alternative to my approach? A lot of questions and answers have been in StackOverFlow but I could not seem to get a clear answer. The iOS 7 background mode only allows 3 minutes. I tried creating another timer that runs for 2 minutes to "wake up" the app so it doesn't get suspended by iOS, but this consumes a lot of battery. I have added the location background mode but I need to get the location every 15 minutes repeatedly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291825/how-to-run-a-30sec-process-in-the-background-every-hour-iphone-app