# iOS5 - Downloading 100MB in background when app is not running

Tags: ios5

iOS5 has multi tasking enabled feature.
So, When the app is in background mode, can I download the data in background?
Will apple permit to write such code?
If yes, any examples will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. You could use one of methods described in [iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events) to get 'constat background' for you

But Apple is very unlikely to approve such abuse for AppStore