# How to keep my app longer than 10 min. in the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, background

I know that in iOS, background apps can only be running

- Finite-length tasks (10 min)
- Location updates
- VoIP
- Audio

Is there a way for my application to avoid being terminated after being 10 min. in the background? I will not be submitting my app to the app store, so everything is allowed (private frameworks, using the gps even if I don't need it) I know apple does not recommend this, but it is just for monitoring purposes. I need it to be running without a limit.

I explored several possibilities including the VoIP , but it only gives me 30 seconds every 10 minutes, which is not enough. I also read this post:
[iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)
in which JackPearse specified a way to "revive" the 10 minute finite-length task using the VoIP 30 second task. But I don't want my task to start and end every 10 minutes, it must run continuosly.
I also tried his UPDATE2, but it's not working for me.
I even tried intercepting the UIEvent with GSEvent.type 2012, which seemed to be the one ending my background task, but no luck. Strangely, my background task is never ended when I have Xcode opened and debugging, but when I don't (test the simulator alone) it ends after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to keep my Application in the background for longer than 10 minutes by continuously playing a song in the background.
On the AppDidFinishLauching:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...]; //Song URL
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

player.numberOfLoops = -1;
[player play];
```

In the AppDidEnterBackground you can perform a selector in background, which can last forever. The App will not be interrupted, you can check UIApplication backgroundtimeRemaining and see it never decreases.

Of course, declare the app as a background audio App in the plist.

Comment: My application is a voip application and it should receive notification or incoming calls with sound when the application is in background. But with the above solution it is not playing the notification sounds. Any solution ? :-)

Comment: You should not use this for normal apps! Mine was for investigation and intern distribution. This is not any official way of keeping your app in the background.

Comment: so you put that code in appdidfinishlaunching? and then you put what in appdidenterbackground?

Comment: In appDidEnterBackground, you can start a thread on the background like this

    [myClass performSelectorOnBackground:@selector(doThis)];

Comment: Hi George, I have a question. If I perform a selector(doThis) in appDidEnterBackground, doThis will run in background without the limitation of 10 minutes? does doThis need to be a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier? a little confuse about this. Thx.

Comment: It is a bug, yes, and you're not supposed to do it. But it runs without the 10 minute limitation in the background. I do not know about the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.
Note that if you do this, your app will certainly not be accepted in the app store: this was merely for a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

I have already tried some way(**nsrunloop**,**performselectoronmainthread**) like that.It's works well in **simulator** (not  in device because apple crashes automatically after sometimes) when the  app goes to background.

status is a BOOL variable.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    while (!**status**) {
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0]];
        [self goBackground];
    }
}
```