# iOS background polling without location services

Tags: objective-c, background, location, voip

this is a question we've all wondered about a number of times, and no one seems to have a good answer.

How do apps like DataMan run on a regular basis in the background, indefinitely, and still get into the app store?

The app allows a user to turn on "precise data tracking" and select a frequency at which the app updates it's data usage counters with zero user interaction - the intervals are once every minute, once every 10 minutes, and once every 20 minutes.

Yes, I've read all the associated [Apple Documentation on background processes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) and implemented many of them successfully. I've also [explored the ins and outs of this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events/4808049#4808049), but it's old enough now that many of those "loop holes" have been patched and the documented stuff works better anyway.

While I've had great luck with registering my app as a VOIP app and requesting a keep-alive at certain intervals, it's not app-store-ok unless it's a VOIP app (DataMan isn't). Furthermore, registering for VOIP keep-alives doesn't actually exhibit the same behavior as DataMan...VOIP keep-alive calls come at somewhat-random intervals, or at least at the frequency you select without syncing up to clock time. DataMan actually falls in line with clock-mandated intervals and updates its data counters at the :10, :20, :30 minute marks, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [their support site](http://xvision.me/support), their pro version just got pulled by apple.  I would bet that their other versions are next.

Just because you manage to sneak something past the review team doesn't mean they won't catch it later, or that other people will succeed.  What they're doing is clearly against Apple's guidelines if they are not also offering one of the approved background services.