# Schedule Tasks to execute methods in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, nstimer

I would like to schedule tasks in iOS to execute a method depending on the time of the day and the day.
For example, I want to execute startMonitorRegion every day at 10pm and stopMonitorRegion at 10am. I don't want to send a local notification to alert the user, it needs to be transparent for the user.

Is anyway to do it using NSTimer? The app will be in background.

Comment: Even if the app will be in background, it can execute tasks during only 10 mins. So, I think, there is no solution other that to use notifications.

Comment: you can check below link.You may get solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events

Comment: find a answer to this?  ios7 has some features that may help.

Comment: Which features do you mean Patrick?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Local notifications for this purpose.

Just schedule local notification for some date/time. and once user open your app you can perform the required task..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we don't want to user Local notifications because it should be transparent for the user