# Programmatically minimize iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I need to programmatically minimize my iPad application. `exit(0)` didn't do  what I required. Is this possible and if so how? I don't need to worry about AppStore rejections.

Comment: Why you are looking for such code. if home button exactly do the same

Comment: I mean problematically. That is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Apple do not recommend (and don't allow, will reject your app during review) an iOS application programatically quit.

You should read Apple's Technical Q&A at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html 
And also "Don’t Quit Programmatically" in the [User Experience Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)

You may argue that minimizing is not quit, but the principle is Apple wants the user have the ultimate decision on leaving an app.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, you can only "minimize" the app **problematically** - because it is very **problematic** to just quit on the user *programmatically*.

For sending your app to the background, this is an old problem e.g. [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Not in this case. There is a linguistic problem and a programming problem that is answered on this platform. Links to answers on this platform are encourage rather than regurgitating content again.

Comment: You should take it **pragmatically**. ;)