# Infinite background execution on iPhone

Tags: ios, background, voip

I'm developing iOS application that should do some background work with specific interval (30-3600 seconds) so ideally I'm need infinite background execution for my app. I'm using "update 1" solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events/4808049#4808049) answer but there is one problem.

1. I'm using `setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:` to register keep-alive handler in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate method and;
2. Calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`;
3. Moving app to background. Everything is fine. Timers are firing, work in progress, `backgroundTimeRemaining` says i have ~600 seconds;
4. After 600 second app is suspended;
5. After few seconds keep-alive handler calling and requesting background execution again. But this time `backgroundTimeRemaining` says i only have about 50 seconds;
6. After 50 seconds the application is suspended again;
7. ~550 seconds suspend;
8. GOTO 5.

I'm testing my app on iPhone 3GS with latest version OS (6.1.3).
So the question is why I'm getting only about 50 seconds after second time call for `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`?
Is there any other way to do some work with short-time interval (e.g. 30 seconds) in background on iOS?

PS: Application I'm developing is for in-company usage, so I don't care about rejecting it by Apple.