# How does the IFTTT app do background sync?

Tags: iphone

Is there any code that can illustrate how IFTTT does background sync?

It's basically a geolocation hack, but I'm wondering how it exactly works.

Comment: Is there a bot that automatically downvotes every question that gets asked now? This seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if this is what they're using, but you mentioned that it's a geolocation hack, and [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) says (under "Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks") that you can add `location` to the `UIBackgroundModes` in an app's `Info.plist` to execute tasks in the background.

You'll need to go a bit beyond this to execute tasks even when the location hasn't changed -- see [How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application/6465280#6465280) for how you could implement this, and [iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events) for other methods of executing background tasks (in addition to using the geolocation hack).