# iPhone App running in background and sending data to the server

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm planning to develop an app reading data usage from the iPhone like each app internet usage , 3G, WiFi etc. My question is:

V1. Is it possible to keep app running in the background (even when is killed) and collecting a data and sending to the server every 15min?

V2. Is it possible to keep app running in the background (even when is killed) and collecting a data and send the data to the server once is reopen?

There are apps like which have similar functionality:

http://www.mobidia.com/products/takecontrol/

http://xvision.me/dataman

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're allowed to do either when the app is in `suspended` mode. There is no app code being executed at that state.

When your app is in `background` though there is only a limited number of tasks you are allowed to perform.

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background.
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

For more info look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

Comment: How than apps like this works: http://www.mobidia.com/products/takecontrol/

http://xvision.me/dataman

Comment: Where does it say that the app will continue if "killed"?

Comment: But V2 might be possible. Collect data to the local storage (within the app and sync once has been re-open when I push some notification.

Comment: Or there is something new here: http://www.xcubelabs.com/blog/ios-7-background-execution-and-multitasking/ what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not possible to keep your app open if the user force quits, which I believe is what you mean by killed.

As far as background execution goes check out this informative answer: [iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)

In that answer it says you can't make recursive beginBackgroundTask calls, but I've seen a method where you make that call and then start location updates before the task dies. Then immediately shut of location updates and begin another background task.
[Here is a link to that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application/6465280#6465280)

Comment: What About this -> http://www.xcubelabs.com/blog/ios-7-background-execution-and-multitasking/

Comment: Using the fetch and remote-notification background modes would be good for syncing the data. Remote-notification might even work for periodically collecting some data since you can send them silently and not disturb your users. I haven't used NSURLSession yet so I can't really speak to its effectiveness for your scenario.