# iPhone - NSLog does not print when app is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nslog

One of my `VoIP` enabled app prints log for every 5 mins interval when app is in background.

But this log did not show at the time of log time.

All log shows at the moment of application coming to foreground by pressing on it.

But why?

Any help please.

Comment: Plz try this link for background task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events

Comment: @satheeshwaran NSLog works while app is in background.

Comment: A bit hard to assess without some code around the App delegates. I am guessing you already have the background mode enabled for VoIP?

Comment: Yes already enabled for VoIP

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Swift print function:**

The print() function does log to the Target Output on Xcode in background. 
I verified it on iOS 8.1 (on the phone, not simulator) and the logs are printed by background location updates.