# In iOS, is there a way to execute a piece of code after certain amount of time after I quit the application?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to execute a piece of code after certain amount of time after I quit the application?

**I mean press the home button**

Comment: you might want revise your question

Comment: Excite the code? Well, I suppose you could use a feather to tickle the iDevice's ram chips and hope you hit the transistors where your code's being stored...

Comment: What state is your application in when you want to execute your code? If you need help figuring this out, take a look at [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: See applicationWillEnterBackground and applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: How much time is "a certain amount"?  Seconds?  Minutes?  Hours?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Backgrounding to poll for events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:

The `applicationDidEnterBackground` method is called on the `appDelegate` in iOS 4.0 and onwards, upon the home button being pressed and the user's view exiting to the home screen. You can then use a [`NSTimer`]

(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

to execute whatever code you want at some point later. Note, though, that iOS likes `applicationDidEnterBackground` to return within about 5 seconds; your application can start a background task with the method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> Your app delegate’s **applicationDidEnterBackground:** method has
>   approximately 5 seconds to finish any tasks and return. In practice,
>   this method should return as quickly as possible. If the method does
>   not return before time runs out, your app is killed and purged from
>   memory. If you still need more time to perform tasks, call the
>   **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:** method to request background execution time and then start any long-running tasks in a
>   secondary thread. Regardless of whether you start any background
>   tasks, the **applicationDidEnterBackground:** method must still exit
>   within 5 seconds.

Read the whole article for more information but basically when someone presses the home button the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method will get called. In that method setup your code on a separate thread using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

if You want to execute some code after some time than you can use the NSTimer.Thanks

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(MethodName)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
```