# AFNetWorking executes setCompletionBlock after 30 seconds if app is inactive

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I am using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for download of files in one of my project.

Everything is working properly for download if my app is awake.

The error occurs in below scenario.

- I keep for download.
- I navigate away from app for 30+ seconds
- When I come back, it executes `setCompletionBlock` and because of this my download is incomplete.

If I comes back to app before 30 seconds, download continues.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

---

I tried setting timeout interval for NSURLRequest to 300, but still it execute `setCompletionBlock` after 30 seconds.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:currentURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
  timeoutInterval:300];
operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation start];
```

Comment: You could try to use AFHTTPRequestOperation and see what happen

Comment: @LucaIaco : I am using `operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];`

Comment: Ok, so maybe you don't enable background task execution ( that should allow you to continue operation execution up to 600 seconds before kill them). see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808049/3172445 (at Update 2) it could helps

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. See the *Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background* section of the [iOS App Programming Guide:App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3). Basically, before you start your network request, inform the OS that you want to request additional time to complete this network request if the app happens to go into the background:

   ```
   UIApplication *application = [UIApplication defaultApplication];

   bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
       // stopped or ending the task outright.
       [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
   ```

   This assumes you have some instance variable or class property for that `bgTask`:

   ```
   UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
   ```

   Anyway, inside the network request's completion block, end the background task:

   ```
   if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) { 
       [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   });
   ```

   If you do the above, the app will be allowed to have a few minutes to complete the network request when the app enters the background. Note, if you have multiple requests running in the background, you will presumably want a separate `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` for each request.
2. In iOS 7.0 and later, you have `NSURLSession`, which permits a much richer background network request mechanism. AFNetworking offers `AFURLSessionManager` as an interface for `NSURLSession`, but it's nowhere as robust as `AFHTTPRequestManager`.

   See the *Background Transfer Considerations* section of the [URL Loading System Programming Guide: Using URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1). Basically, you need to:

   - Create `NSURLSessionConfiguration` using `backgroundSessionConfiguration:` (in iOS 8, it's `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:`).
   - Issue only `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` or `NSURLSessionUploadTask` requests.
   - Use the delegate-based implementation of those `NSURLSessionTask` factory methods.
   - Make sure to implement `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` in your app delegate, saving the `completionHandler`.
   - Implement a `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` method in your `NSURLSessionDelegate` object.